Styling a "programmatically created block" in drupal 10
I'm new to Drupal dev, I'm messing around creating some custom modules and explore how the env of drupal 10 works...
I've created a custom block that i called "Copyright":
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Drupal\plugin_play_module\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\Attribute\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup;

#[Block(
    id: 'copyright_block', // id is the internal machine name,
    admin_label: new TranslatableMarkup('Copyright'),
    category: new TranslatableMarkup('Custom')
)
]
class Copyright extends BlockBase
{
    #[\Override]
    public function build(): array
    {
        $date = new \DateTimeImmutable();

        return [
            '#markup' => \t('Copyright @year&copy; My Company', ['@year' => $date->format('Y')]),
        ];
    }
}


and after I placed it in footer region using UI, I wanted to style it a little...
Based on some inspection:

I have added some css:
.block__content{
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
}



but at the end, nothing changed
here's the config for that custom module :
#plugin_play_module.info.yml
name: Plugin Play Module
description: playing with plugins
type: module
core_version_requirement: '>=9'
libraries:
  - plugin_play_module/copyright_block

#plugin_play_module.libraries.yml
copyright_block:
  css:
    layout:
      css/styles.css: {}

here the tree structure of the web/modules/plugin_play_module
│   ├── plugin_play_module
│   │   ├── **css**
│   │   │   └── styles.css
│   │   ├── **js**
│   │   ├── plugin_play_module.info.yml
│   │   ├── plugin_play_module.libraries.yml
│   │   ├── plugin_play_module.module
│   │   ├── plugin_play_module.services.yml
│   │   ├── **src**
│   │   │   └── **Plugin**
│   │   │       ├── **Block**
│   │   │       │   └── Copyright.php
│   │   │       ├── ...


Did you rebuild cache after adding the library? Have you checked the page source to see if your styles are included? If they are, have you inspected the element to ensure your CSS has the required specificity?

You can't add libraries from module info files, this only works with themes. You have to use a different way, like simply attaching it in the block build function. Read https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/creating-modules/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-module-via-librariesyml

Another kettle of fish you might need to do some research on is the Drupal caching system. I know it's not mega important in this exampe but your year value won't magically update if the block is being cached (which it is by default)
